# Spring JDBC DataSource Connection - Address already in use: connect

Tags: spring, jdbc

We are using Spring Batch in a multi-threaded environment. We are using a connection pool to obtain connections from the database. But few of the threads throws an exception while trying to execute a proc. Database Connection settings, maxthreads = 120.

We are running batch from Windows 2008 machine using Oracle JDK 7, Spring 4, ojdbc6.jar.

Could you please let me know what could be the cause and mitigation?

```
<bean id="pooledDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driver}" />
        <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${jdbc.user}" />
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
        <property name="defaultAutoCommit" value="false" />
        <property name="defaultTransactionIsolation" value="2" />
        <property name="maxTotal" value="#{${maxThreads}*5}" />
        <property name="maxIdle" value="10" />
        <property name="poolPreparedStatements" value="true" />
        <property name="maxOpenPreparedStatements" value="100" />
        <property name="minEvictableIdleTimeMillis" value="-1" />
        <property name="removeAbandonedTimeout" value="900" />
        <property name="removeAbandonedOnMaintenance" value="true" />
        <property name="testOnBorrow" value="true" />
        <property name="logAbandoned" value="true" />
        <property name="timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis" value="20000"/>
    </bean>
```

Exception

```
2018-01-09 06:57:07.334 ERROR o.s.batch.core.step.AbstractStep - Encountered an error executing step aStep in job cycleJob
com.test.system.exception.BackEndSystemException: error
    at com.test.system.batch.CycleDAO.loadStatus(CycleDAO.java:759) ~[xxxxxxx-batch-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at com.test.system.batch.CycleItemWriter.write(CycleItemWriter.java:78) ~[xxxxxxx-batch-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor74.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317) ~[spring-aop-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190) ~[spring-aop-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) ~[spring-aop-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:133) ~[spring-aop-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:121) ~[spring-aop-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207) ~[spring-aop-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy20.write(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.writeItems(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:175) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.doWrite(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:151) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.write(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:274) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.process(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:199) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.ChunkOrientedTasklet.execute(ChunkOrientedTasklet.java:75) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:406) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:330) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:133) ~[spring-tx-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:271) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:77) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:368) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:144) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.doExecute(TaskletStep.java:257) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:198) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.partition.support.TaskExecutorPartitionHandler$1.call(TaskExecutorPartitionHandler.java:139) [spring-batch-core-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.partition.support.TaskExecutorPartitionHandler$1.call(TaskExecutorPartitionHandler.java:136) [spring-batch-core-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [na:1.7.0_79]
    at org.springframework.core.task.SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor$ConcurrencyThrottlingRunnable.run(SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor.java:251) [spring-core-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_79]
Caused by: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:458) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.jar:11.2.0.3.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:546) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.jar:11.2.0.3.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:236) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.jar:11.2.0.3.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.jar:11.2.0.3.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:521) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.jar:11.2.0.3.0]
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverConnectionFactory.java:39) ~[commons-dbcp2-2.1.1.jar:2.1.1]
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:256) ~[commons-dbcp2-2.1.1.jar:2.1.1]
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.create(GenericObjectPool.java:868) ~[commons-pool2-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:435) ~[commons-pool2-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:363) ~[commons-pool2-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.PoolingDataSource.getConnection(PoolingDataSource.java:134) ~[commons-dbcp2-2.1.1.jar:2.1.1]
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1533) ~[commons-dbcp2-2.1.1.jar:2.1.1]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:104) ~[spring-jdbc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy$TransactionAwareInvocationHandler.invoke(TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy.java:225) ~[spring-jdbc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy31.prepareCall(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.test.system.batch.CycleDAO.loadStatus(CycleDAO.java:745) ~[xxxxxxx-batch-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    ... 32 common frames omitted
Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
    at oracle.net.nt.ConnStrategy.execute(ConnStrategy.java:392) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.jar:11.2.0.3.0]
    at oracle.net.resolver.AddrResolution.resolveAndExecute(AddrResolution.java:434) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.jar:11.2.0.3.0]
    at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.establishConnection(NSProtocol.java:687) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.jar:11.2.0.3.0]
    at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:343) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.jar:11.2.0.3.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1102) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.jar:11.2.0.3.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:320) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.jar:11.2.0.3.0]
    ... 47 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:85) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at oracle.net.nt.TcpNTAdapter.connect(TcpNTAdapter.java:150) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.jar:11.2.0.3.0]
    at oracle.net.nt.ConnOption.connect(ConnOption.java:133) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.jar:11.2.0.3.0]
    at oracle.net.nt.ConnStrategy.execute(ConnStrategy.java:370) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.jar:11.2.0.3.0]
    ... 52 common frames omitted
```

Comment: And you expect us to guess the actual values of the properties? Please add the property values as well.

Comment: Already mentioned maxThreads = 120. Rest I believe is immaterial.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as the only property values we can't see are the URL, user and password and maxThreads, I'm not sure how adding these will help.

The issue here is that the connection pool is trying to add new connections to it and Oracle is refusing to create them, so your pool is set up to use more connections than Oracle is willing to dole out.

To fix your issue I'd actually reduce the number of connections in your pool to something Oracle can cope with, and set maxWaitMillis on the pool to an appropriate value (the default is to wait forever which you may or may not want).

This will allow the Spring Batch threads to sit there waiting for a connection from your connection pool, rather than you getting failures when the connection pool tries to allocate a connection.

In other words, try a connection pool with less connections than the maximum Oracle allows, and less than the number of threads you're running.

You're currently setting the max total connections to be 5 times the number of threads.If you're getting anywhere near this level of usage you may have a connection leak.